# Binding of regular function to std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functional-programming, operator-overloading

I am trying to code a functional composition using operator overloading in C++, so to have a simple composition syntax similar to the ones in functional languages (e.g. Haskell). My aim is to use regular bare C++ functions in the composition. There are two overloads which I coded so far:

1. `operator%` which uses two `function<int(int)>` parameters and
2. `operator*` which uses template type as parameters.

`operator%` works well, but in main() I have firstly to wrap regular functions into `function<int(int)>` in order `operator%` to accept them as input parameters. I want to avoid this additional step by migrating it into overloaded `operator*` which uses template parameters. I thought that it is possible to bind regular functions to the template parameters of `operator*`, but compiler reports the error:

```
composingFunc.cpp11.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
composingFunc.cpp11.cpp:28:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘int(int)’ and ‘int(int)’ to binary ‘operator*’
   cout<<(f*g)(5)<<endl;
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? Using template parameters in `operator*`is not mandatory - if you have some other approach simply suggest here.

Here is the source code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

using namespace std;

int f(int n)
{  return 2*n; }

int g(int n)
{  return n+1; }

function<int(int)> operator%(function<int(int)> f, function<int(int)> g)
{ 
  return [=](int x){ return f(g(x));};
}

template<typename T>
function<int(int)> operator*(const T &f, const T &g)
{
  function<int(int)> f1=f,f2=g; //this is encapsulated here so it is not
                                //necessary to repeat the same in main 
                                //for every functional composition
  return [=](int x){ return f1(f2(x));};
}

int main()
{
  function<int(int)> f1=f, f2=g; //I want to encapsulate this step into operator*
  cout<<(f1%f2)(5)<<endl; //this works well
  cout<<(f*g)(5)<<endl; //error in this line
}
```

**EDIT:** Solution given by Zac uses a class type for one of function arguments (it is mandatory, by the standard, to use at least one enum or class type argument in operator overloads) and a template type argument. Then regular C++ functions gladly bind to both arguments. Thus the final operator overload is quite simple:

```
template<typename T>
function<int(int)> operator*(function<int(int)> f, T g)
{
    return [=](int x){ return f(g(x));};
}
```

and regular functions can be composed then using simple `(f*g)(x)` syntax.

Comment: maybe you should read: http://blogea.bureau14.fr/index.php/2012/11/function-composition-in-c11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, one of the argument in the operator overload has to be class or enumerated type. Therefore the call to `f*g` needs to be instantiated to `function<int(int)>` instead of function pointer type. There are two options for this problem,

1. use function instead of operator, such as

   ```
   template<typename T>
   function<int(int)> multi(T x, T y)
   ```
2. declare one of the function parameter as `function

   ```
   template<typename T>
   function<int(int)> operator*(function<int(int)> x, T y)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Zac! The second option solves the problem! I already started to lose hope ;)

Comment: @RobinRobinovic How does this work? It certainly [does not work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6b11b68536fa7f2) for me. What compiler do you use that accepts this? Also note that, reading the first sentence of this answer, that one of the arguments **of the call itself** (not of the overloaded operator's declaration) must be of class or enumerated type!

Comment: @Daniel Strange, it compiles perfectly with g++ v4.8.1. on my laptop at home (even calling by cout<<(f*g)(5)<<endl;). It doesn't work with g++ v4.5.1 on the computer at my office (reports the same error as in your case), but it works if called using operator*(f,g)(5). Take a look at my last edit in the initial post: you don't need the line function<int(int)> g2=g;

Comment: @RobinRobinovic Yesterday I asked about the [difference between `a+b` and `operator+(a,b)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307578) in a separate question, the answer from Dietmar explains it. Why GCC 4.8.1 would accept the code `(f*g)` is still a mystery to me and I'm sure it's not standard conforming, so I wouldn't rely on it!

Comment: @Zac I am still puzzled why the overload with one std:function parameter is accepted but not with both parameters.

Comment: @RobinRobinovic I am also confused by the contradictory behavior from different gcc versions. My intention is to force the conversion from `int(int)` to `function<int(int)>`, but it seems the standard simply wont consider that as a function if operator * is called with only built-in types. I doubt there could be a solution for your problem at this point. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The only idea that comes to mind is to start with some dummy:

```
struct F{}F;

function<int(int)> operator*(struct F, function<int(int)> g)
{
    return g;
}

function<int(int)> operator*(function<int(int)> f, function<int(int)> g)
{
    return [=](int x){ return f(g(x));};
}

int main()
{
    cout<<(F*f*g)(5)<<endl; // start with F, then add the real stuff
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this would solve the problem. Besides this solution cannot compile: composingFunc.cpp11.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
composingFunc.cpp11.cpp:37:13: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘std::function<int(int)>’ and ‘int(int)’)
   cout<<(F*f*g)(5)<<endl;

Comment: @RobinRobinovic It does compile [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26614e7837b1a67f). (You can also switch to GCC4.8, that also works) (but yes, it's not really a solution).

Comment: Yes it works now :) I copied the code before your recent edit - that one did not compile well in fact. So, the problem for a desired solution is that at least one of arguments has to be of class (struct) or enum types, to which ones the regular function does not belong. I wonder if the problem of the initial post is possible to solve with C++.